# Using Markov - Chain to find average and probability

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Suppose a computer generate a random vector of n positions where each position appears on of the numbers from 1 to n. The generation is performed uniformly on the $n!$ possibilities.
In the problem we must guess each position by following these rules

a) You write you guess vector and then discovers how many correct answers. 
b) As you guess, the value is informed in position. So whether or not you know exactly what went wrong and occupies one position.

Let $N_{a}, N_{b}$ the number of hits you get in each of the above rules. How do I calculate the averages of $N_{a}$ and $N_{b}$ and the probability of hitting at least 50% of their guesses for $n = 10$

In the case 1) I suppose that if the Markov - Chain is not necessary. Because I think would only need to calculate the probability of 1 hit, 2 hits ... and so on and take the average, however how can I calculates this probability not sure. I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about the wording, but it sounds like RULE A involves guessing with no feedback (so each position $i$ has one of $n$ possible values), while RULE B allows you to make a guess about position $i$ after seeing the previous $i-1$ results (so that the value in position $i$ is only one of $n-(i-1)$ possibilities).

Comment: In either case you can define $X_i$ as an indicator function that is $1$ if your guess is correct in position $i$, and $0$ else, so that $NumCorrect = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ and $E[NumCorrect] = \sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i]$.

Comment: Calculating probabilities that a certain number of guesses are correct requires more info on the guessing strategy.  For example, under RULE A you can guess {1,1,1,..1}, in which case you will surely get exactly 1 right.  Or you can guess {1,2,3,..,n}, in which case you might get them ALL right. The expected number of correct guesses would be the same, though.

Comment: Sorry.The problem basically is, I think a vector of n positions, (1,3,2) for exemple,  and you try to guess all positions. In the RULE B. for each position $i$ is informed whether you hit or not and also what the number at position. In the RULE A, is informed only the amount of positions you hit. Get the ideia ? My english is not very good.

Comment: what vector?  The guessing vector?  Of course, only under RULE A would you use a permutation of {1,...,n}.  Under RULE B it would be silly to do so, since the feedback might suggest you to repeat a guess.  You will always get the last position correct under RULE B, as I understand it.

Comment: Yes, the computer generates a permutation of 1 to n, so I try to guess the permutation of two ways, A and B. In A permutation I guess, so I know how many hit. In B I'm picking the numbers and being informed whether or not hit. For each error I know which number. Knowing whether hit or not affects the probability of next choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a), the average value $N_a$ can be found using linearity of expectation. 
\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{E}_a(n) &= n\cdot \frac{1}{n} = 1
\end{align*}

and for $n=10$, the probability of atleast half of them to be correct is:
\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}_a\left(\text{at least 5 correct positions}\right) &= \sum_{i=5}^{10}\frac{\binom{10}{i}\cdot !(10-i)}{10!} \\
  &= \frac{4421}{1209600} \approx 0.00365492724867725
\end{align*}

where the notation $!i$ indicates the number of derangements.

For (b), I'm going according to Michael's interpretation that we guess numbers one after another, and our guess depends on previous decisions.

Expectation seems to have the recurrence:

\begin{align*}
\color{#c00000}{
  \mathbb{E}_b(n)} &= \color{#c00000}{\mathbb{E}_b(n-1) + \frac{1}{n}} \\
  \color{#c00000}{\mathbb{E}_b(1)} &= \color{#c00000}{1}
\end{align*}
or 
\begin{align*}
  \color{#c00000}{\mathbb{E}_b(n)} &= \color{#c00000}{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}=H_n} \\
  \color{#c00000}{\mathbb{E}_b(10)} &= \color{#c00000}{\frac{7381}{2520}\approx 2.93}
\end{align*}

**Update**

*My previous attempt solving case (b) is incorrect, the corrected version follows*:

My simulation was not agreeing with part (b), and I was thinking for a while about the optimal strategy and finally found a paper.

Exactly the same problem and much more has been discussed in [this paper](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/81_16_feedback.pdf) by Persi Diaconis and Ronald Graham.

Hence, on using the optimal strategy discussed in theorem 5, i.e. Keep guessing 1 till it's correct, then guess 2 till it's correct and so on,

\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{E}_b(n) &= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k!} \\
  \mathbb{E}_b(10) &= \frac{6235301}{3628800}\approx 1.71828180114638
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}_b(G\ge k) &= \frac{1}{k!} \\
  \mathbb{P}_b(G\ge 5) &= \frac{1}{5!} \approx 0.00833
\end{align*}

and this time everything agrees with the simulation.

Comment: Thanks for the great help. In case B as would find that probability of more than 5 correct positions?

Comment: You are welcome. I am trying to figure out the probability for case B, will edit when I find.

Comment: Ok, thanks again.

Comment: @user50098 : Hi, now I have corrected and completed the answer for case B. You may find it interesting to read the paper I have linked.

Comment: Very cool interesting outcome too

Comment: Really! thanks for help

Comment: You are welcome! @user159813 : Didn't notice you were a different user, glad that you enjoyed too.

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems here is you would like to just treat this as iid random variables such as using bernoulli trials for each answer but the problem they are not independent. Once I answered 3 for question one we then know that question two can not be 3 (thus not independent it gives us information when conditioned) But we could run a quasi simulation in R to get a rough estimate of expected number of correct answers. I will look at case n=10

For Rule A) This is my R code

```
#This will be the correct answers
#the position is the question while number is what is correct #answer

ans=sample(1:10,10,replace=FALSE)

#I am assuming that our guess vectors are also just uniformly from
#the n! possibilities 
numCorrect=NULL
for(i in 1:1000)
{
guess=sample(1:10,10,replace=FALSE)
correct=which(guess==ans)
numCorrect[i]=length(correct)
}

#By Law of Large Numbers this should be close to true mean
mean(numCorrect)

#This will count how many simulations have 5 or more right answers
geq5=NULL
for(i in 1:length(numCorrect))
{
if(numCorrect[i]>=5)
{
    geq5[i]=1
}
else
{
    geq5[i]=0
}
}

#Again By Law of Large Numbers this should be close to probability
mean(geq5)
```

From this we get about a average of 1 answered right with a 0.005 probability of answering 50% right

**NOTE I am pretty rusty with R so if anyone sees anything wrong do comment about

Also just quick question what is easiest way copy paste code I tried using pre formatted but I had to indent each line which was tedious

Comment: Thanks for help, you know get this result without being a simulation?

Comment: I'll have to think about it I forgot that @Michaels way he suggest doesn't depend on independence so that actually may work for Rule to find expected just 10(1/10)=1

Comment: Thanks. Think the dependency is only on rule B.However I could not turn this exercise into a Markov process

Comment: Yea in terms of whether correct or not only matters for b for dependence

Comment: Then in the rule A the average would b 10*1/10 = 1, like you foun in your code

Comment: @user50098  : The fact that an expectation of a sum is the sum of expectations does not require independence. The formula I gave for $E[NumCorrect]$ above gives a very simple exact answer for both RULE A and RULE B (of course the answer for RULE B will be better since $E[X_i]$ is better for $i>1$). However, I don't know a simle way to get the probability that more than half are correct.

Comment: But the odds of success are different it would not change the mean? Because if I'm in the position $i$ and know if it's right or not, affects the choice of position i + 1. Creating a markov chain.

Comment: Yes, in RULE B, $E[X_i]$ will be different (but calculatable) for each $i$, and then you just sum. The answer should grow logarithmically in $n$.  I am assuming that before your guess at position $i$, you know all numbers in positions $\{1, \ldots, i-1\}$.

Comment: Exactly, I'm also assuming that just do not know yet how to find this probability, you have any idea?

Comment: Possibly for rule A may be able use binomial dist

Comment: For RULE B under $n=11$, try running your simulation to compute the expected number of successes. The exact answer for $n=11$ is $\sum_{i=1}^{11}E[X_i]=83711/27720 \approx 3.0198773$.  I wonder how close the simulation would get...?

Comment: Ok I'll have to edit code but I'll see what I get.

Comment: For RULE B: I don't see what "Because if I'm in the position $i$ and know if it's right or not, affects the choice of position $i+1$" means.  From my understanding of the problem, the only thing that affects your guess in position $i$ is knowledge of the true answers in positions $\{1, \ldots, i-1\}$.  Whether or not your guesses were correct in those previous positions is irrelevant.

Comment: This may be wrong but let's say I got number 1 right now I'm choosing uniformly from a n-1 answers but if was wrong still choose uniformally from n answers

Comment: I know your position "i" then reduces the sample space of the next choice probability increases as soon as I know all the numbers {1, ..., i-1} is thus a markov chain

Comment: For your question about copying the code preformatted, I think writing a script for that is the easiest. E.g. using sed : `cat filename | sed 's/^/> /'`

Comment: Sweet Thanks so much

Comment: Also I don't know two much about Markov Chains but doesn't it usually depend on that at in some form or another it information from the conditional probability follows some cycle (such that it doesn't need all information) if that is the case then I not know if you could do that in this case since to find probability of an answering is correct lets say for question 10 you need to know what if answers were correct or not for ALL previous questions. I just took quick look at this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain

Comment: at least to use them in a meaning full way